# Update "What is an acceptable answer?" FAQ

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Our [What is an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer) FAQ still contains the following:

```
 5 You missed a comma,         "            Vote to close as         Yes
   which is causing                          too localized.
   the error
```

How should we deal with these kinds of questions now that [too localized has been removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons)?

Example: [Show data of a month instead of 12 months](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17363666/211627)

This question is not a code dump... the OP simply made a minor mistake and didn't bother to investigate their code very carefully. In the past I would have voted to close as too localized (a bug in their code is not going to help future visitors), but now I can't find an appropriate close reason.

Also, someone needs to update the FAQ.

Comment: Wha!  That's not NAA even if the question *is* too localized.  You shouldn't flag the answer at all.  Currently what to do with the questions is under debate though; I'd save making a note of this for until those discussions are resolved.  Perhaps just remove that line entirely in the mean time.

Comment: Personally, I'd probably leave your example question be, but simply add the answer from the comment into an actual answer. I think one thing that the community is struggling with right now is that there seems to be a wide range of what kinds of "typos" people consider "Too Localized".

Comment: @Servy - I was a little surprised by that advice as well. I was going to suggest to ajakblackgoat that the response should really be an answer, but I checked myself first against the FAQ. It appears s/he was actually following the FAQ.

Comment: Related: [How to flag a typo question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186366).  Also, what am I missing here? [What is an acceptable answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer) doesn't characterize answers posted to these types of questions as NAA, only that the question itself is too localized.

Comment: @joran: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186405 for some guidance in this area.  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186376 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186181/now-when-too-localized-is-gone-should-we-embrace-the-typo-questions/186196#186196

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Also, that fourth column is title "NAA".

Comment: @Cyborgx37: I wouldn't bother flagging that one.  It's a well-written troubleshooting question.  "Too Localized: Fix my Typo" is more for questions where the OP headdesks, and leaves a comment to the effect of "stupid error, left out a comma."

Comment: @Cyborgx37: `Also, that fourth column is title "NAA"` Ah, I see that now.  Well, I think that should be changed to "No."

Comment: @Cyborgx37, sorry I was referring to the part about "Someone needs to update the FAQ". Since it's a community wiki, you can edit it as you see fit. My previous comment was misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I changed the following:

1. On item 5, changed "Flag as NAA" from "Yes" to "No."  That *is* an answer.  Changed "Vote to Close as Too Localized" to "Flag as Too Localized, Fix My Typo."
2. On item 7, changed "Flag as NAA" from "Depends" to "No."  There is no guidance on what "depends" means, and incorrect answers should be downvoted and/or commented, not flagged as NAA.

Comment: can we post that information somewhere which supports table? That faux table looks a bit squiggly.